# Testing AngularJS behavior between pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor

I have an Angular application that has two pages: A login page and a landing page. I want to implement a Protractor assertion that tests when a valid page login fires, and then confirms the landing page loads valid contents.

The login prompt itself checks for a valid user by making a JSON call to an endpoint, and if successful, uses a window redirect to load the landing page. It works outside the context of testing, but when the following assertion case runs, it stops at the waiting process and then eventually finishes without having asserted.

```
//Attempt to login with a valid Username and Password
it('should attempt to login with valid credentials', function() {
    element(by.css('#login_username')).sendKeys('testusername');
    element(by.css('#login_password')).sendKeys('testpassword');
    element(by.css('.btn-default')).click();

    browser.driver.sleep(20000);

    //H1 on landing page
    expect(by.css('h1').html()).toEqual("Landing");

});
```

I am not clear on whether or not in the event the button form submit would be enough to pause protractor while it eventually loads the next page, or if I am missing a step in the drafting of the test. Any ideas on what to do next?

Comment: To use '.sleep' is very bad.
It's better to use a callback functionality for that

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it works

```
//Attempt to login with a valid Username and Password
it('should attempt to login with valid credentials', function() {
    element(by.css('#login_username')).sendKeys('testusername');
    element(by.css('#login_password')).sendKeys('testpassword');
    element(by.css('.btn-default')).click();

    //H1 on landing page
    expect(by.css('h1')).then(function (event) {
        toEqual("Landing");
    });
});
```